# why STL set size complexity is O(1), how is it calculated?

Tags: c++, stl, set, std

A set is internally maintained as a balanced binary tree. The complexity to calculate the size of set is O(1). How the size is calculated, does it maintain any variable to store the size.

Comment: The standard never defines how a something should be done. It defines requirements like `O(1)` and then leaves the details of how to achieve this to the library implementors. But keeping a variable with the number of elements seems like an easy way to do this. Note: The standard does not say that a set needs to be a balanced binary tree. It specifies some access characteristics (which can be achieved with a balanced binary tree thus it is potentially a way to implement a std::set).

Answer (score 3):

The specification states only that all `set`s (actually, all containers) have a `size()` member function that takes constant time. Other than that, the implementers of your particular version of the standard library may have done it however they wished, as long as it's `O(1)`.

In practice, the size may well be stored in a member variable that gets updated as items are inserted or removed; PiotrNycz' implementers have done just that.

Answer (score 0):

When you RTFS - you can see that yes - the member variables counting nodes in RB-Tree, which is base for stl-set is there.

E.g. see https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_tree.h :

```
size_type _M_node_count; // keeps track of size of tree

size_type size() const { return _M_node_count; }

template <class _Key, class _Value, class _KeyOfValue, 
          class _Compare, class _Alloc>
typename _Rb_tree<_Key,_Value,_KeyOfValue,_Compare,_Alloc>::iterator
_Rb_tree<_Key,_Value,_KeyOfValue,_Compare,_Alloc>
  ::_M_insert(_Base_ptr __x_, _Base_ptr __y_, const _Value& __v)
{
  // ...
  ++_M_node_count;
  return iterator(__z);
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that this is completely up-to-date for all possible implementations.